# Show adverts for "Android Stack Exchange" on Stackoverflow for questions tagged Android

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, tags, advertising, android

Likewise for other side.

It seems that a lot of people asking questions about Android on SO do not know about  "[Android Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/)".  Can this be changed with some adverts?

Comment: The problem is that most people on SO are [trying] to ask questions about Android *programming*, which is not on topic on Android.SE. From the [FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq): "Android - Stack Exchange is not for programming questions. Please ask your developer questions on StackOverflow."

Comment: @Cody True but I agree about the faact that they can be interested in android.se

Comment: Yes, it wouldn't hurt to advertise it. And I'd honestly be in favor of *anything* that helps to clean up the disaster area that is the Android tags. Right now, it's a really good reason for me not to try and learn Android development.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's already a rather prominent link to [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) on the [android](/questions/tagged/android) tag. Considering the (comparatively) large number of questions we're migrating from Android Enthusiasts to Stack Overflow, and not vice versa, it seems to be sufficient.